# GWT/Sencha GXT Text area validation shows false negative

Tags: gwt, textarea, gxt

Even though GWT text area contains text when the validate is method is called it fails.

```
 //Populating the data in a seperate method
 evntCommonWidget.getDescription().setText(obj.getDescription());

 //test to check whether data is getting populated
 int curPos=this.getDescription().getCurrentValue().length();
 GWT.log("text area text size "+curPos);
 this.getDescription().setAllowBlank(false);

//Validation process 
if (!description.validate()) {
    this.getDescription().focus();
    return false;
}
```

Log shows,
00:12:12.550 [INFO] text area text size 4.

What is going wrong ? Please help to resolve

Comment: When do you call the validate method? GXT updates the value on blur, so maybe the text area's value has not been updated yet?

Comment: I call the validate() after populating the values as shown in code sample.

Comment: This "populating" is what interests me :)

Comment: I have edited the code to show that the first line of code is in a seperate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is mentioned in the javadocs for [`setText`](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/ValueBaseField.html#setText(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine):

> Sets the underlying DOM field's value directly, **bypassing validation**. This
>   method does not update the field's value. **To set the value with validation
>   see `setValue`**.

You should use the `setValue(value, true)` method instead - `true` is needed to fire the `ValueChangeEvent` and trigger validation.